# asymptotic properties for a local linear estimator evaluated at the boundary vs interior

Tags: regression, kernel-smoothing

Suppose I have local linear estimator at $x$ defined as

$(\widehat{a}_{x},\widehat{b}_{x})=\underset{a_{x},b_{x}}{argmin}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(Y_{i}-a_{x}-b_{x}(X_{i}-x))^2k(\frac{X_{i}-x}{h})$,

where $x$ has support $[\underline{x},\overline{x}]$ with $-\infty<\underline{x}<\overline{x}<\infty$ and $k(\cdot)$ is the kernel function and $h$ is the bandwidth.

My question is:

What is the asymptotic distribution of $(\widehat{a}_{x},\widehat{b}_{x})$ when $x$ is at the boundary ($\underline{x}$ or $\overline{x}$)? How does it differ from when $x$ is at interior?

Insights or guidance with detailed derivation/reference paper/book chapter are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: In what sense can you ask about asymptotics?  If $x$ is obtained from a continuous distribution, almost surely it will not be on the boundary.  Shall we therefore assume the distribution has nonzero probability at its boundary?  And if so, what sense would a kernel density estimate have?  What would it be estimating?

Comment: @whuber thanks, your comments helps me clarify the question. $x$ cannot be infinity here, otherwise this local linear regression is not defined. So if $x$ is finite, and the support of $x$ is $R$, any $x$ is in the interior, so we go back to the standard case. Thus the only relevant question is: what happens if $x$ has finite support and sits at the boundary. I have this question as a note says if $x$ is at the boundary then the estimator converge slower than at interior but I didn't see how. (I know that boundary creates a bias of larger order than interior, but local linear fixes it.)

Comment: I don't know the answer but I do know that whenever any statistical theorem is derived ( be it regarding MLE, Cramer Rao Lower Bound etc ), they always assume that one is in the interior of the parameter space and that the " standard regularity conditions" hold. Maybe regularity conditions don't hold at the boundary ?

Comment: @mlofton Thanks! It's helpful.

Comment: I'm glad that it's slightly helpful. If I had more time, I'd check it out just to try to learn something  so you may want to look at the specific meaning of "regularity conditions". That might lead to something.